# Mongo find() to return all documents is slow for certain documents

Tags: find, pymongo

I'm experiencing an issue when using PyMongo to iterate over all documents in a particular collection.  The loop needs to scan about 450k documents, and it is nearly instant on almost every document except for a handful where a single iteration takes 10-90 seconds.

```
for testscriptexec in testscriptexecs.find({}, {"tsExecId": 1,"involvedOrgs": 1, "qualifiedName": 1, "endTime": 1, "status": 1}):
```

I'm trying to figure out what is slowing down the Cursor on certain documents.  I determined that the long delays always occur on the same documents.

I compared the JSON export for a slow document and compared it to a fast one and I do not see anything that should be slowing down the indexed search on _id.  The documents are not particularly large and the fields that I'm actually pulling are exactly the same size.

The collection has an index on _id, as well as a few other indices that are not relevant to this code.

What are some things that could be causing this query to hang on certain iterations of a find by ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These questions are always a bit subjective, but one thought is MongoDB returns data in batches, so that could explain what you are seeing.

You could rule this in or out by tweaking the batch_size parameter on your `find()` https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.batch_size